# PHP Xdebug - Dump particular $_SERVER variable in log file

Tags: php, command-line-interface, xdebug

I'd like to include the value of an environment variable in the logs with xdebug, it works perfectly in the standard output, but the logs are slightly different in the log file and it doesn't display the enviroment variable I defined in xdebug.ini.

**xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 2048
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 8
xdebug.dump.SERVER = 'HOME'
```

**Test code (test.php):**

```
<?php
phpinfo_wrong();
?>
```

**Standard output (Looks good)**:

```
root@localhost:~# php ./test.php 

Fatal error: Call to undefined function phpinfo_wrong() in /root/test.php on line 2

Call Stack:
    0.0001     219784   1. {main}() /root/test.php:0

Dump $_SERVER
   $_SERVER['HOME'] = '/root'
```

**Log file (Missing environment variable):**

```
[28-Jul-2015 20:57:05 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function phpinfo_wrong() in /root/test.php on line 2
[28-Jul-2015 20:57:05 America/New_York] PHP Stack trace:
[28-Jul-2015 20:57:05 America/New_York] PHP   1. {main}() /root/test.php:0
```

Comment: Which environment variable would you like to include?  Or, specifically, what exactly should the log file contents look like?

Comment: @kdbanman I have a custom environment variable that I'd like to show in the log. It should look just like the output. Format can be different, as long as the environment variables defined with xdebug.dump.SERVER are there.

Comment: So this looks good? `$_SERVER['HOME'] = '/root'`  Which means your log file should have a line `[28-Ju...York] PHP SERVER['HOME'] = '/root'` or something similar?

Comment: And the environment variable you're talking about in your question is `HOME`, right?

Comment: @kdbanman, that's correct. HOME is just an example. Like I said, I'm gonna display a custom environment variable. I should be able to catch any environment variable in the logs with Xdebug, not just in the output.

Comment: You're right, that sounds like a reasonable goal.  Hopefully someone with Xdebug experience sees this.